# How to find ChangeCol1/ChangeCol2 and %ChangeCol1/%ChangeCol2 of DF

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have data that looks like this.

```
    Year  Quarter  Quantity  Price  TotalRevenue
0   2000        1        23    142          3266
1   2000        2        23    144          3312
2   2000        3        23    147          3381
3   2000        4        23    151          3473
4   2001        1        22    160          3520
5   2001        2        22    183          4026
6   2001        3        22    186          4092
7   2001        4        22    186          4092
8   2002        1        21    212          4452
9   2002        2        19    232          4408
10  2002        3        19    223          4237
```

I'm trying to figure out how to get the 'MarginalRevenue', where:

```
MR = (∆TR/∆Q)
```

MarginalRevenue = (Change in TotalRevenue) / (Change in Quantity)

I found: df.pct_change()
But that seems to get the percentage change for everything.

Also, I'm trying to figure out how to get something related:

```
ElasticityPrice = (%ΔQuantity/%ΔPrice)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you mean something like this ?

```
df['MarginalRevenue'] = df['TotalRevenue'].pct_change() / df['Quantity'].pct_change()
```

or

```
df['MarginalRevenue'] = df['TotalRevenue'].diff() / df['Quantity'].diff()
```